# Display array in kivy Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, kivy

Instead of printing the array in console I want to show it in the window. The array calculates in the other class function.

```
class ThirdWindow(Screen):

    def display(self):
        i=int(funi.abc)
        j=int(funj.abc)
        arr=funarr.abc
        order = int(ord.abc)
        n = int(inc.abc)
        for i in range(order):
            for j in range(order):
                print('%4d ' % (arr[i][j] * n), end=" ")
            print()
```

Answer (score 0):

class ThirdWindow(Screen):

```
def display(self):

    i=int(funi.abc)
    j=int(funj.abc)
    arr=funarr.abc
    order = int(ord.abc)
    n = int(inc.abc)
    for i in range(order):
        for j in range(order):
            self.print_label.text+=("%6d" %(arr[i][j] * n))
        self.print_label.text +="\n"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).